# jquery live() method on custom functions

Tags: jquery

I have a custom event handler, or I suppose some call it a custom jquery function.

My problem is I'm trying to apply the live() method to it.  But I'm not too successful.

Here's a simple custom jquery function:

```
$.fn.myFunction = function() { 
    return $(this).addClass('changed'); 
}
```

And here I use it:

```
$('.changePlease').myFunction();
```

Ok, simple enough.  But how do I apply the live() method to it??

I actually have no idea if that's even possible.
But I do use live() for other things, like:

```
$(".changePlease").live("click",function(){ alert("hello"); });
```

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jquery.live` works only for inbuilt events, and have not been adapted for custom events yet. You might need to find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
$.fn.myFunction = function() { 
  return $(this).live('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('changed'); 
  });
};
```

Not sure what the use case here is. Sounds like you want to load new elements (via ajax or maybe by creating them with another event?), and once they get `click` events, to get the `'changed'` class added to them.